# "Blasphemy" in 1 Kings 21:10

Tags: hebrew, word-study, 1-kings

> "and cause two men -- sons of worthlessness -- to sit over-against him, and they testify of him, saying, Thou hast blessed God and Melech; and they have brought him out, and stoned him, and he dieth.'" 1 Kings 21:10 YLT, [bolls.life/YLT/11/21/10](https://bolls.life/YLT/11/21/10)

Why in YLT in the text translator write **"blessed"** when in other translations written this:

> "and seat two worthless men before him, and let them testify against him, saying, 'You cursed God and the king.' Then take him out and stone him to death.'" 1 Kings 21:10 NASB, [bolls.life/NASB/11/21/10](https://bolls.life/NASB/11/21/10)
>
> «And set two worthless men opposite him, and let them bring a charge against him, saying, 'You have **cursed** God and the king.' Then take him out and stone him to death."»
> ‭‭1 Kings‬ ‭21:10‬ ‭ESV‬‬

Comment: This question seems to have been asked and answered already here: [In what sense is the word בּרך (blaspheme) used in 1 Kings 10:9 & 1 Kings 21:10](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/26042/in-what-sense-is-the-word-%d7%91%d6%bc%d7%a8%d7%9a-blaspheme-used-in-1-kings-109-1-kings-2110)